# Add OG meta tags to wp head

Tags: wp-head, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm using gravity forms and on thank you page I would like to be able to add some of the fields into to head OG meta tags. So far I have this:

After Gravity forms submission we get the needed fields

```
function after_submission( $entry, $form ) {

    $name = $entry[2];
    $item = $entry[5];

    insert_og_in_head( $name, $item );

}
add_action( "gform_after_submission", "after_submission", 10, 2 );
```

Write the metatags to head

```
function insert_og_in_head( $name = NULL, $item = NULL) {

    global $post;
    if ( !is_page( 6 ) ) //if it is not a post or a page
    return;

    echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . $name . ' lorem opossum dolor"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:description" content="' . $item . ' lorem." />';
    echo '<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>';
}
add_action( "wp_head", "insert_og_in_head", 5 );
```

It gets the needed fields from forms correctly, it gets to function where it supposed to write them, but still on my head the field parts are empty. What I'm doing wrong? I somehow feel it goes twice to insert_og_in_head function, first time writes correctly but on second time it overrides with empty.

Comment: You are echoing the meta tags only for page with ID equal to 6. `if ( !is_page( 6 ) return` That means: it not is page with ID 6, then return.

Comment: The form thank you page is ID 6 so that is correct. Like I said, I believe it loads it once but for some reason it goes twice and second time makes the variables empty

Comment: The variables `$name` and `$item` are not valid parameters of `wp_head`; if they are added by gravity form plugin you should ask to gravity form support.

Comment: No, trouble is not getting the data form. I get them. But inserting them into to head is problem.

Comment: When you execute `insert_og_in_head` in `wp_head`, `$name` and `$item` are `null` because they are not valid parameters for `wp_head` callbak. If you execute `insert_og_in_head` in `after_submission` (callback of `gform_after_submission`) the meta are not printed in the head (or maybe yes, I don't know how `gform_after_submission` works). As we don't know how or when `gform_after_submission` works, we can not help you. You should ask to gravity form support or try another way to get form data in `wp_head`, maybe using `$_POST` or `$_GET` inside `wp_head` callback depending on the form method.

Answer (score -1):

Well You can also try by adding action inside.

```
function after_submission( $entry, $form ) {

    $name = $entry[2];
    $item = $entry[5];

    insert_og_in_head( $name, $item );
    add_action( "wp_head", "insert_og_in_head" );

}
add_action( "gform_after_submission", "after_submission", 10, 2 );

function insert_og_in_head( $name = NULL, $item = NULL) {

    global $post;
    if ( !is_page( 6 ) ) //if it is not a post or a page
    return;

    echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . $name . ' lorem opossum dolor"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:description" content="' . $item . ' lorem." />';
    echo '<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>';
}
```